# How to change inactive tab colour background on click

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm not well-versed in HTML and CSS but basically, I have a page with tabs. When I click a button I want the colour scheme to change, including the original background colour of the button container.

```
<div id="container">

    <!-- tab buttons -->
    
   <div id="btncontainer">
   

        <button class="buttonnorm tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab 1')"
        id="defaultOpen">
        
            <span class="chaname">usagi tsukino</span>
            <br>
            <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
            
        </button>
    
        <button class="button2 tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab 2')">
            
            <span class="chaname">ami mizuno</span>
            <br>
            <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
            
        </button>
```

If I try to create a separate div thing [meaning a btncontainer2] with a different colour background, how can I implement this to change upon opening the tab?
If you need to see what I've got so far, I'm only worried about the tab group on the left. Let me know if any more info is needed.
https://glaceontea.tumblr.com/mediatest
https://pastebin.com/8wsEjavY

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JavaScript as well on your website? This would be the easiest to add onClick() listener for that button, find your button with getElementsByClassName (Maybe consider adding ID to buttons if you want to target them easier with getElementByID) and then change the css attributes through JavaScript.

Let me know if this will work or you need help on the implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you add a common class to all the `tabcontent` type div elements you can simplify the javascript considerably and make it applicable to any number of tabs/buttons with no headaches when registered as an external event listener.

Here I used `.tab` as the common className so that I could easily identify these tabs ( it is just one of several ways of identifying these elements btw ) and assign an event listener to each button identified using `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#btncontainer button').forEach( (bttn,index)=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  
  let i=index+1;
  let expr='Tab '+i;
  
  // hide all elements of class `tab`
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  col.forEach( n=>n.style.display='none' );

  // set current tab as visible block
  document.getElementById(expr).style.display='block';
  
  // find and remove active class from all relevant nodes
  col=document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');
  col.forEach( n=>n.classList.remove('active') );
  
  // apply background colour to button parent and assign current button as `active`
  e.currentTarget.parentNode.className='CUSTOM_BACKGROUND_'+i;
  
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
}));
```

```css
.CUSTOM_BACKGROUND_1{
  background:#8494A9!important;
}
.CUSTOM_BACKGROUND_2{
  background:#B1F0F9!important;
}
.CUSTOM_BACKGROUND_3{
  background:#BAE6C3!important;
}
.CUSTOM_BACKGROUND_4{
  background:#ECB1F5!important;
}













.tmblr-iframe {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%); 
    -moz-filter: invert(100%); 
    -ms-filter: invert(100%); 
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%); 
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    transform: scale(0.7,0.7);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    white-space: nowrap;
} 
 
.tmblr-iframe:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --------------------------- custom tooltips --------------------------- */
 
.tippy-tooltip.custom-theme {
    background-color: #ee959e;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -------------------- custom selection & scrollbar --------------------- */
 
::-moz-selection {background: #ee959e; color: #ffffff;}
::selection {background: #ee959e; color: #ffffff;}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
{background: #fab1b9; border: 5px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{background: #141414; border: 7px solid #ffffff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{width: 15px;}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ----------------------------- page layout ----------------------------- */
 
body {
    background: #ffffff;                /* background color */
    color: #141414;                     /* text color */
    font-family: Poppins;               /* font */
    font-size: 15px;                    /* font size */
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;            /* text letter spacing */
    line-height: 160%;                  /* text line height */
    text-align: justify;                /* text align */
}
 
#container {                            /* content container */
    height: 620px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 90%;
}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --------------------------------- tabs -------------------------------- */
 
#btncontainer {                         /* button container */  
    background-color: #fab1b9;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    -moz-overflow-style: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    -o-overflow-style: none;
}
 
#btncontainer4 {                         /* button container 4 */  
    background-color: #4d8f5f;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    -moz-overflow-style: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    -o-overflow-style: none;
}
 
.tabcontent {                           /* tab container */ 
    background-color: #f6f2fc;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
}
 
.tabcontent2 {                           /* tab container 2 */ 
    background-color: #adcdf0;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
}
 
.tabcontent3 {                           /* tab container 3 */ 
    background-color: #caadf0;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
}
 
.tabcontent4 {                           /* tab container 4*/ 
    background-color: #dcf7e3;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px - 40px);
}
 
.buttonnorm {                  /* buttons */        
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.button2 {                  /* button 2 */        
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.button3 {                  /* button 3 */        
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.button4 {                  /* buttons */        
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
 
/* active button and hover */
 
.buttonnorm:hover, .buttonnorm.active{
    background-color: #ee959e;
}
 
.button2:hover, .button2.active{
    background-color: #6185ab;
}
.button3:hover, .button3.active{
    background-color: #8161ab;
}
.button4:hover, .button4.active{
    background-color: #7fc993;
}
 
.buttonnorm::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
.chaname {font-size: 1.2em; text-transform: uppercase;}
.chasubtitle {font-size: 0.9em; font-style: italic; padding-left: 20px;}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------- content ------------------------------- */
 
#leftcontent {                          /* left content in tab */
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 250px - 40px - 20px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 250px - 40px - 20px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px - 40px - 20px);
}
 
#linkbox {                              /* top left link and quote box */
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% + 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + 40px);
}
 
#quote {                                /* quote box */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
#quote i {                              /* quote icons */
    color: #fab1b9;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
 
#quote2 i {                              /* quote icons */
    color: #3d76b3;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
#links {                                /* link bar */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fab1b9, #ee959e);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 25px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
}
#links2 {                                /* link bar 2*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d76b3, #09407a);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 25px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
}
 
#links a {                              /* links */
    color: #ded9da;
    font-size: 19px;
}
#links2 a {                              /* links2 */
    color: #ded9da;
    font-size: 19px;
}
 
#links a:hover {                        /* links hover */
    color: #ff7a95;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
}
 
#links2 a:hover {                        /* links2 hover */
    color: #23384f;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
}
 
#bio {                                  /* bio section */
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 220px);
    overflow: auto;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% + 40px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + 40px);
    -moz-overflow-style: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    -o-overflow-style: none;
}
 
/* gives links in bio section a bottom border */
 
#bio a {border-bottom: 3px solid #fab1b9;}
#bio a:hover {border-bottom: 3px solid #ee959e;}
 
#facts {                                /* right bottom info */
    height: calc(100% - 270px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 270px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 270px);
    line-height: 139%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: none;
}
 
img:hover {cursor: cell;}
img {border-radius: 20px; width: 250px;}
#bio::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
.answer {float: right; margin-left: 7px;}
#rightcontent {float: right; height: 100%; width: 250px;}
.prompt {background-color: #ee959e; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px 8px;}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -------------------------------- text --------------------------------- */
 
h1 {                                    /* character name */
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-overflow-style: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    -o-overflow-style: none;
}
 
a {
    color: #fab1b9;                     /* link color */
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
a2 {
    color: #3d76b3;                     /* link2 color */
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {   
    color: #ee959e;                     /* link hover color */
}
a2:hover {   
    color: #09107a;                     /* link2 hover color */
}
 
.firstword {color: #ee959e;}
h1::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------- transitions ------------------------------ */
 
a, a:hover, a2, a2:hover #credit, #credit:hover, button, button:hover, button4, button4:hover{
    transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ----------------------------- responsive ------------------------------ */
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #quote {height: 95px;}
    #linkbox {height: 210px;}
 
    #bio {
        height: calc(100% - 270px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 270px);
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 270px);
    }
}
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #quote {height: 65px;}
    #linkbox {height: 180px;}
    #rightcontent {margin-top: 20px;}
    .tabcontent::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
    #leftcontent, #rightcontent {float: none; width: calc(100% - 40px);}
 
    .tabcontent {
        overflow: auto;
        -moz-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -o-overflow-style: none;
    }
    .tabcontent2 {
        overflow: auto;
        -moz-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -o-overflow-style: none;
    }
    .tabcontent3 {
        overflow: auto;
        -moz-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -o-overflow-style: none;
    }
    .tabcontent4 {
        overflow: auto;
        -moz-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -o-overflow-style: none;
    }
 
    #bio {
        height: calc(100% - 220px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 220px);
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 220px);
    }
 
    img {
        width: calc(100% + 40px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% + 40px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% + 40px);
    }
}
 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------- credits ------------------------------- */
 
#credit {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #fab1b9;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
}
 
#credit:hover {
    background-color: #fab1b9;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="btncontainer">
  <button class="buttonnorm tablinks active" id="defaultOpen">
    <span class="chaname">usagi tsukino</span><br>
    <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
  </button>
  <button class="button2 tablinks">
    <span class="chaname">ami mizuno</span><br>
    <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
  </button>
  <button class="button3 tablinks">
    <span class="chaname">rei hino</span><br>
    <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
  </button>
  <button class="button4 tablinks">
    <span class="chaname">makoto kino</span><br>
    <span class="chasubtitle">sailor moon</span>
  </button>
</div>



<div id="Tab 1" class="tab tabcontent" style="display: block;">
   <div id="leftcontent">
      <h1><span class="firstword">usagi</span> tsukino</h1>
      <div id="linkbox">
         <div id="quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            girls have to be strong to protect the men they love
            <i class="fas fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
         <div id="links"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-hat-cowboy" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-tools" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-radiation" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-skull-crossbones" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-crow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-hammer" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bio">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="rightcontent"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/0ebf1e3381365b16b33d25bdecbf117b/8f55519f8fad3e4e-10/s250x400/580220f8f5fee91b0309d40472ab09c4d1891196.png"><!-- facts -->
      <div id="facts"><span class="prompt">senshi name</span><span class="answer">sailor moon</span><br><br><span class="prompt">age</span><span class="answer">14</span><br><br><span class="prompt">gender</span><span class="answer">female</span><br><br><span class="prompt">sexuality</span><span class="answer">bisexual</span><br><br><span class="prompt">alignment</span><span class="answer">chaotic good</span><br><br><span class="prompt">zodiac</span><span class="answer">cancer</span><br><br><span class="prompt">birthday</span><span class="answer">june 30</span><br><br><span class="prompt">height</span><span class="answer">1.5 m</span></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="Tab 2" class="tab tabcontent2" style="display: none;">
   <div id="leftcontent">
      <h1><span class="firstword">ami</span> mizuno</h1>
      <div id="linkbox2">
         <div id="quote2"><i class="fas fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            be pure, be honest, be beautiful
            <i class="fas fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
         <div id="links2"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-tree" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-water" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-seedling" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-snowflake" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bio">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="rightcontent2"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/50fea5f245734d1fc1f5b85a67f09894/tumblr_psusqs3NH31u4buxw_250.jpg"><!-- facts -->
      <div id="facts2"><span class="prompt">senshi name</span><span class="answer">sailor mercury</span><br><br><span class="prompt">age</span><span class="answer">14</span><br><br><span class="prompt">gender</span><span class="answer">female</span><br><br><span class="prompt">sexuality</span><span class="answer">asexual</span><br><br><span class="prompt">alignment</span><span class="answer">lawful neutral</span><br><br><span class="prompt">zodiac</span><span class="answer">virgo</span><br><br><span class="prompt">birthday</span><span class="answer">september 10</span><br><br><span class="prompt">height</span><span class="answer">1.57 m</span></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="Tab 3" class="tab tabcontent3" style="display: none;">
   <div id="leftcontent">
      <h1><span class="firstword">rei</span> hino</h1>
      <div id="linkbox">
         <div id="quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            i shall punish those who steal pure hearts to destroy innocent lives with the fire of mars
            <i class="fas fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
         <div id="links"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-moon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-sun" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-meteor" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-space-shuttle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bio">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="rightcontent"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/ac674f03dc750c712230e83ec85ba5cf/d98316f0f765c3e8-41/s250x400/7e0c373b6010f073801ccb83b78a4e2095d11a73.png"><!-- facts -->
      <div id="facts"><span class="prompt">senshi name</span><span class="answer">sailor mars</span><br><br><span class="prompt">age</span><span class="answer">14</span><br><br><span class="prompt">gender</span><span class="answer">female</span><br><br><span class="prompt">sexuality</span><span class="answer">heterosexual</span><br><br><span class="prompt">alignment</span><span class="answer">true neutral</span><br><br><span class="prompt">zodiac</span><span class="answer">aries</span><br><br><span class="prompt">birthday</span><span class="answer">april 17</span><br><br><span class="prompt">height</span><span class="answer">1.6 m</span></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="Tab 4" class="tab tabcontent4" style="display: none;">
   <div id="leftcontent">
      <h1><span class="firstword">makoto</span> kino</h1>
      <div id="linkbox">
         <div id="quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            how dare you destroy my precious lunch box! | I'll make you feel regret, it'll leave you numb!
            <i class="fas fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
         <div id="links"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-tree" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-water" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-seedling" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href=""><i class="fas fa-snowflake" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bio">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="rightcontent"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/34352616dab51ba5003b7d0029dc21e8/be1a62031dc1914e-e0/s250x400/48eae314a8f879e29f6ab106c921499c045b24c6.png"><!-- facts -->
      <div id="facts"><span class="prompt">senshi name</span><span class="answer">sailor jupiter</span><br><br><span class="prompt">age</span><span class="answer">14</span><br><br><span class="prompt">gender</span><span class="answer">female</span><br><br><span class="prompt">sexuality</span><span class="answer">pansexual</span><br><br><span class="prompt">alignment</span><span class="answer">lawful good</span><br><br><span class="prompt">zodiac</span><span class="answer">sagittarius</span><br><br><span class="prompt">birthday</span><span class="answer">december 5</span><br><br><span class="prompt">height</span><span class="answer">1.67 m</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Is there any simple way to make it so that for each tab, a different colour for the btncontainer is set? (Sorry if it's already in there)